# Avoid confilicts in sequential threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I need to create a loop of the following way:

```
while (!end) {

     // some modifications to myPar

     boost::thread t(&myClass::myFun, this, myPar);

     // other operations
}
```

At each iteration, I want the thread to start only when the one called at the previous iteration has finished. But I don't want the "other operations" to wait for it.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't played with boost::thread, but something similar to this should work

```
boost::thread t;
while (!end) {

     // some modifications to myPar
     if(t.joinable())
          t.join();

     t = {&myClass::myFun, this, myPar};

     // other operations
}
```

EDIT
regarding comments you can do something like this

```
class Worker
{

public:
    void addParams( const SomeParams &params)
    {
        paramsQueue.push(params);
    }

    void start()
    {
        auto loop = [this]()
        {
            while(!interrupted)
            {
                //BLOCK HERE if queue is empty

                auto params = paramsQueue.pop();

                //do something with params
            }
        };

        thread = {loop};
    }

    void interrupt()
    {
        interrupted = true;
    }

private:
    boost::thread thead;
    std::queue<SomeParams> paramsQueue;
    bool interrupted = false;
};


...

Worker worker;

worker.start();

while (!end) {

     // some modifications to myPar

     worker.addParams(params);

     // other operations
}
```

But remember to implement blocking, because you'll have UB if you'll try to read on empty queue. Also push and pop from queue must be thread safe.

Comment: Wouldn't this delay the "other operations" to be executed?

Comment: wich other operations? @charles, you need to run on parallel just the operations you can perform without waiting

Comment: If you wanna run myFun parallel but only one at once, create something like class with queue of params, which will in other thread run myClass::fun sequentionally with params from queue